# UITableView didSelectRow while editing?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm building an interface much like the built-in Weather application's flipside view, or the Alarms view of the Clock application in editing mode. The table view is always in editing mode, so the delete icon appears on the left side of each cell.

When the table view is in editing mode, my delegate doesn't receive `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` notifications. It receives `accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath` notifications, but that's not what I want to do. I want my rows to stay selectable, even when the table view is in editing mode.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks,

P.S. Hooray for the lifted NDA. =)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Set `table.allowsSelectionDuringEditing` to `YES`.

Comment: D'OH! Thanks. I don't think it's mentioned in the SDK documentation, though.

Answer (score 12):

You can also set this in the attributes inspector.  Make sure you select the table view, not the view controller, and select "Single Selection During Editing" in the Editing dropdown:[image]