# Selecting row while UITableView is in editing mode

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, select, row

I have a UITableView where when I put it in editing mode, I want selective rows to be selectable, however, they are not. Is there a way I can force them to be selectable?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

Set the `UITableView` property [allowsSelectionDuringEditing](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614889-allowsselectionduringediting?language=objc) to `YES`.

Comment: also for actions you could do `if (tableView.editing == YES)` in `didSelectRow`. Just a tip.

Comment: This can also be set in interface builder (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174309/uitableview-didselectrow-while-editing)

Answer (score 0):

Set "Editing" property to "Single Selection During Editing"